# Sorting sqlite table showing in my listview not working in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, listview

I am using the following to sort a table of players based on their position

```
public ArrayList<Player> getAllPlayers()
{
    ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PLAYERS + " ORDER BY "+"p_position"+" ASC";

    // Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Player td = new Player();
            td.setPlayerId((c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TABLE_PLAYERS_ID))));
            td.setPlayerName((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TABLE_PLAYERS_NAME))));
            td.setPlayerPosition(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TABLE_PLAYERS_POSITION)));
            td.setPlayerNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TABLE_PLAYERS_NO)));


            // adding to todo list
            players.add(td);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return players;
}
```

I am trying to sort my table which is displayed in a listview but sorting has no effect why is that?

Comment: Did you tried adding logs in do-while loop to check whether or not you are getting the sorted rows from the query you made?

Comment: not actually , shall I sort my returned arraylist instead?

Comment: Yup you can. That would fix your issue.

Comment: how to sort an arraylist based on column position??

Comment: Can you post your database schema?

Comment: Sort your list using - Collections.sort(players). But for this you need to implement Comparator/Comparable interface for your Player class.

Answer (score 0):

Its called whenever the user clicks a button and I pass the appropriate variables like String SortBy which is the column of which I want to sort by

```
public Cursor getSortedAllMyPlayers (int tm_id,String SortBy) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String buildSQL = "SELECT *, p_id as _id FROM " + STATS_TABLE_PLAYERS +" WHERE p_team_id="+tm_id+" ORDER BY "+SortBy+" ASC";

    //Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

    return db.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}
```